# why is texture painting messing up so bad?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

here's a video of what's going on. i thought i unwrapped it just fine, it's a really simple mesh so i don't get whats happening. i applied all transforms and tried to unwrap it differently and it still does this. why??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recalculated my normals and that fixed the issue!